# Sorting a multidimensional dimensional array of x,y coordinates in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, numpy, multidimensional-array

So I am attempting to sort a multidimensional array of elements in python.  The array is a mess which is what makes it so hard, but unfortunately it is what the opencv function returns.

These are y,x coordinates (backwards I know....)

```
[array([[[ 13, 178]],[[ 50, 179]],[[ 49, 258]],[[ 12, 257]]]), 
array([[[ 58,  93]],[[105,  94]],[[104, 171]],[[ 57, 170]]]), 
array([[[ 13,  93]],[[ 50,  94]],[[ 49, 171]],[[ 12, 170]]]), 
array([[[ 58,   9]],[[105,  10]],[[104,  86]],[[ 57,  85]]]), 
array([[[13,  9]], [[50, 10]],[[49, 86]],[[12, 85]]]), 
array([[[ 58, 178]],[[105, 179]],[[104, 257]],[[ 57, 257]]])]
```

Now the way I need this sorted is by the first element of each numpy array (lets call it a), and then the SECOND element of a in DESCENDING.  And I need all ties to be broken on the FIRST element of a in ASCENDING order.

So this would end up being

```
[array([[[ 13, 178]],[[ 50, 179]],[[ 49, 258]],[[ 12, 257]]]),
array([[[ 58, 178]],[[105, 179]],[[104, 257]],[[ 57, 257]]]),
array([[[ 13,  93]],[[ 50,  94]],[[ 49, 171]],[[ 12, 170]]]),
array([[[ 58,  93]],[[105,  94]],[[104, 171]],[[ 57, 170]]]),
array([[[13,  9]], [[50, 10]],[[49, 86]],[[12, 85]]]),
array([[[ 58,   9]],[[105,  10]],[[104,  86]],[[ 57,  85]]])]
```

Now, I have figured out how to access these elements using

```
items[each][first][0][Y_POS(or X_POS)]
```

where each is the nparray to access (there are 6 of them)
and Y_POS refers to the y position and X_POS refers to the x position.

The other two variables first and 0 will never change.

I really have no idea where to start with this to make it run efficiently, so any help is appreciated.  Keep in mind that the coordinates are in Y,X notation.

Thanks in advance everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Given that A is the 4d array containing all your data:

```
I = np.argsort(A[:, 0, 0, 0])
A = A[I[::-1]]
I = np.argsort(A[:, 0, 0, 1], kind='mergesort')
A = A[I[::-1]]
```

First we sort on Y in reverse order, then sort on X in reversed order too, resulting in descending in X but ascending in Y when X is equal. Note that we have to use a stable sorting algorithm to prevent scrambling the results from our first sorting; mergesort should do the trick.